# How to read xml to combobox in datagrid?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I am trying to read xml file to dataset, and binding the dataset to datagrid

**XML file:**

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Communications>
        <ModelNumber>1</ModelNumber>
        <ParamName>BaudRate</ParamName>
        <ParamValues>
            <ParamValue>9600</ParamValue>
            <ParamValue>19200</ParamValue>
            <ParamValue>115200</ParamValue>
        </ParamValues>
        <DefaultValue>19200</DefaultValue>
        <MaxValue></MaxValue>
        <MinValue></MinValue>
    </Communications>
    <Communications>
        <ModelNumber>1</ModelNumber>
        <ParamName>Parity</ParamName>
        <ParamValues>
            <ParamValue>None</ParamValue>
            <ParamValue>Odd</ParamValue>
            <ParamValue>Even</ParamValue>
        </ParamValues>
        <DefaultValue>None</DefaultValue>
        <MaxValue></MaxValue>
        <MinValue></MinValue>
    </Communications>
        <Communications>
        <ModelNumber>1</ModelNumber>
        <ParamName>StopBit</ParamName>
        <ParamValues>
           <ParamValue>1</ParamValue>
           <ParamValue>2</ParamValue>
        </ParamValues>
        <DefaultValue>1</DefaultValue>
        <MaxValue></MaxValue>
        <MinValue></MinValue>
    </Communications>
    <Communications>
        <ModelNumber>1</ModelNumber>
        <ParamName>DataBit</ParamName>
        <ParamValues>
           <ParamValue>7</ParamValue>
           <ParamValue>8</ParamValue>
        </ParamValues>
        <DefaultValue>8</DefaultValue>
        <MaxValue></MaxValue>
        <MinValue></MinValue>
   </Communications>
   <Communications>
        <ModelNumber>1</ModelNumber>
        <ParamName>SlaveAddress</ParamName>
        <ParamValues>
            <ParamValue>1</ParamValue>
        </ParamValues>
        <DefaultValue>1</DefaultValue>
        <MaxValue>247</MaxValue>
        <MinValue>1</MinValue>
   </Communications>
</NewDataSet>
```

**Read xml to Dataset:**

```
    public ObservableCollection<Communication> GetCommunications()
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml("Communications.xml");
        ObservableCollection<Communication> communications = new ObservableCollection<Communication>();
        foreach (DataRow communicationRow in ds.Tables["Communications"].Rows)
        {
            var c = new Communication((ushort)Convert.ToInt16(communicationRow["ModelNumber"]), communicationRow["ParamName"].ToString(),
                    ds.Tables["ParamValue"].Rows[0][0].ToString(), communicationRow["DefaultValue"].ToString(), communicationRow["MaxValue"].ToString(),
                    communicationRow["MinValue"].ToString());
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["ParamValue"].Rows)
            {
                c.ParamValues.Add(dr[0].ToString());
            }
            communications.Add(c);
        }
        return communications;
    }
```

**Binding Datagrid:**

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ParamValues">                                              
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ParamValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding DefaultValue}" />
            </DataTemplate>                                                           
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

But the above code runs with bug that every column of combobox `ParamValues` has all the `ParamValue` of every table `Communications` [Image detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNWIr.png), could you please tell me how to fix this?Thanks in advance!

Comment: ReadXml is not going to work very well in this case.  You nested tags are too deep.  The first level tag is the DataSet Name.  The second level tag is the DataTable name.  The third level tags are the column names with the innertext being the row data.  You have 4 level of tags so ReadXml is producing more than one datatable.  Some of the data is in table 0 and other parts of the data is in table 1.  You may want to bind to table 1 in stead of table 0.

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is close to it. When I debug the class `GetCommunications()`, I found it returns `communications` each with all the `ParamValue` of all `Commucations` tables, but I don't know how to modify this `GetCommunications()` class. Can you help me?

Comment: It is not simple usually to combine tables once ReadXml creates multiple tables.  It is usually easier to parse the xml with custom code than to use ReadXml.

Comment: How should I parse the xml in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `DataSet` with an `XDocument`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Communication> GetCommunications()
{
    ObservableCollection<Communication> communications = new ObservableCollection<Communication>();
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("Communications.xml");
    foreach (XElement communicationRow in doc.Root.Elements("Communications"))
    {
        var c = new Communication((ushort)Convert.ToInt16(communicationRow.Element("ModelNumber").Value), communicationRow.Element("ParamName").Value,
                communicationRow.Element("DefaultValue").Value, communicationRow.Element("DefaultValue").Value, communicationRow.Element("MaxValue").Value,
                communicationRow.Element("MinValue").Value);

        foreach (XElement paramValue in communicationRow.Element("ParamValues").Elements())
        {
            c.ParamValues.Add(paramValue.Value);
        }

        communications.Add(c);
    }

    return communications;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the best way to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Communications");

            string[] columnNames = doc.Descendants("ParamName").Select(x => (string)x).Distinct().ToArray();

            dt.Columns.Add("ModelNumber", typeof(string));
            foreach (string colName in columnNames)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(string));
            }

            var models = doc.Descendants("Communications").GroupBy(x => (string)x.Element("ModelNumber")).ToList();

            foreach(var model in models)
            {
                var orderedModel = model.Select(x => new { 
                    paramCount = x.Descendants("ParamValue").Count(), 
                    parmName = (string)x.Element("ParamName"),
                    parms = x.Descendants("ParamValue").Select(y => (string)y).ToList()
                }).OrderByDescending(x => x.paramCount).ToList();

                for (int parm = 0; parm < orderedModel.FirstOrDefault().paramCount; parm++)
                {
                    DataRow newRow = dt.Rows.Add();
                    newRow["ModelNumber"] = model.Key;
                    foreach(var col in orderedModel)
                    {
                        if (col.paramCount > parm)
                        {
                            newRow[col.parmName] = col.parms[parm];
                        }
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Since I am using WPF hou should binding to the datagrid combobox in this way?

Comment: Like you would with any DataTable.  Sajeetharan code should now work with my DataTable.